# Android Studio 3.6 canary 4 - Gradle throwing DefaultProjectSyncIssues exception

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I updated Android Studio 3.6 Canary 3 to 3.6 Canary 4, and now when i try to build the project it give errors and did not configure correctly.

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.DefaultProjectSyncIssues

ERROR: Cause: com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.DefaultProjectSyncIssues
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution for this issue.
only change your gradle version in build.gradle to this line

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-alpha04'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Android Studio v3.6.1 it works with

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
```